# loop through dirnames list.remove() is not working

Tags: python, arcgis, arcmap

I am trying to loop through multiple directories and multiple GDB's to create a list of feature classes. The issue that I am having is that when I try to remove certain feature classes from the list, the script is just being ignored or I get an error that says x does not exist in list.(x). The issue with the feature class names is that it has a 3 letters that are unique to each GDB while still having 2 other components that are standard.

Something like this:

directory1 > directory1.gdb > shapes > fc_dir1_feature

&

directory2 > directory2.gdb > shapes > fc_dir2_feature

and so on...

I am using

```
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in arcpy.da.Walk(in_workspace, datatype="FeatureClass",type="Polygon"):
if "dir1" in dirnames:
    dirnames.remove('dir1')
```

Which works fine to remove the feature datasets from the GDB and by extension all feature classes within. But I cannot remove just specific  feature classes.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: The code you show doesn't filter anything... you don't have any directories named 'dir1'. You need an inner for loop that iterates dirnames and checks to see if 'dir1' is in one of those.

Comment: Yes this snippet of script will remove the whole directory and feature classes within. That is where my problem is, I do not want the entire directory gone some feature classes within the directory.

Comment: you have a directory called 'directory1' and directories such as 'fc_dir1_feature' that contain 'dir1', but no directories called 'dir1' itself. So, if your if statement is really `if "directory1" in dirnames:`, then you'll have that problem. I think I know how to solve this and will write an answer.

Comment: Oh yes, I'm sorry youre right. And that is exactly my issue. 'dir1' is just an example of that being the only part of the filename that is different within each directory. Sorry, I'm not very good with my explanation. I have tried some thing like this: 'code'if "dataset" in dirnames:
                for filename in filenames
                                if filename.startswith(‘sl_’) and filename.endswith(‘parks’)
'/code'

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that arcpy.da.Walk works like os.walk (that is, removing a directory from dirnames stops walking to that directory) you should add another for loop to iterate dirnames and apply your filter. Notice that I copied dirnames so that I could call remove without messing up the iterator.

```
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in arcpy.da.Walk(in_workspace, datatype="FeatureClass",type="Polygon"):
    # remove subdirectories that match pattern so they will not be walked
    for dirname in dirnames[:]:
        if 'dir1' in dirname:
            dirnames.remove(dirname)
```

Cribbing from [ArcGIS Resources](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018w00000023000000), you can use regex to filter filenames in several different ways. Here are examples of a regex that removes files that have 'abc', 'def' or 'ghi' in your wildcard slots:

```
import arcpy
import os
import re

workspace = "c:/data"
feature_classes = []

# i dont like abc, def or ghi features so I have a regex to match them
filter_classes_re = re.compile('fc_(abc|def|ghi)_feature$')

for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in arcpy.da.Walk(workspace,
                                                  datatype="FeatureClass",
                                                  type="Polygon"):
    for filename in filenames:
        # only add to feature list if it doesn't match the bad guys
        if filter_classes_re.match(filename) is None:
            feature_classes.append(os.path.join(dirpath, filename))


# alternately, i could extract the wildcard part and compare it outside
# of the regex ... but this will be slower

filter_classes_re = re.compile('fc_(.*?)_feature$')

for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in arcpy.da.Walk(workspace,
                                                  datatype="FeatureClass",
                                                  type="Polygon"):
    for filename in filenames:
        # extract the wildcard part
        match = filter_classes_re.match(filename)
        if match:
            matched = match.group(1)
        else:
            matched = ''
        if matched not in ('abc', 'def', 'ghi'):
            feature_classes.append(os.path.join(dirpath, filename))
```

Comment: The issue is that I am trying to limit files within the directory. I still need to walk the directories and remove certain files. The files are labeled as 'fc_.*_feature'. I will try to apply your script above to work with filenames, would this even work?

Comment: Yes, you can do the same basic thing with filenames. Since filenames aren't needed for further iteration, you create a new wanted_files list, loop through filenames and only stick the ones you want in the list. Then you have to use the list somewhere of course.

Comment: I don't know/understand how to deal with the fact that the file names have a wildcard in them(fc_[wildcard]_feature. I am walking through hundreds of directories and there are multiple files like this that need to be excluded. Everything else I've tried has been ignored.

Comment: @cbrannin I added a second example that shows a couple of ways to use regex to filter your files.

Comment: If I am understanding this correctly, I have to have all wildcard values somewhere for either of these to work?

Comment: @cbrannin - I'm not sure what you need. if I understand this, you want to remove some fc_.*_feature files and keep others. You need some criteria (I used things named 'abc', 'def', 'ghi') to decide. What is your criteria? That's what you use to match.

Comment: When the list is being compiled it still ignores searching just for the feature part in the filename. 

The entire list compiles with every layer that is within the sub-directories.

I am trying to bypass the wildcard so I can filter on the feature (fc_[wild]_feature). I'm not even sure if I am explaining this very well. Sorry and thanks again for all the help.